# LWUIT Virtual Keyboard Events

Tags: java-me, lwuit, virtual-keyboard

I'm Using LWUIT

I have amount text field and when I click it it brings VKB and display it, then I enter my value and I have added dataChanged to this text field and what I want to do is to disable dataChanged until I finish editing in the text field

How to know if the keyboard is displayed or not, please I need an urgent help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why did you need dataChanged to the text field?

Comment: because I don't want to press button to calculate the amount I want to calculate it as soon as I finish writing the value and press the OK button in the virtual keyboard, this is my business logic

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dataChanged(), use `ActionListener`. Add action listener to the text field. Then, write the code with in action listener to execute the action to be performed after click ok.

```
textFieldObj.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           // Your code
       }
});
```

It will work for your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Kalai for your reply, but please could you please tell me how can I get the action of OK button in the VKB to make sure that user has finished editing ? please I'm waiting your response

Comment: That's what I have told. If we add action listener to the textfield, it will work as OK button event in VKB.